# Warning installing SqlAlchemy

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I get this warning while installing sqlalchemy==1.3.3 on python 3.4.2 and Debian 8.11 with `pip3`:

> warning: no files found matching 'sqla_nose.py'

I think it's some unit tests. Sqlalachemy does not have an issue reporter, they suggest to use StackOverflow. So this is not a question but more a bug reporting :) But if you have some suggestion you're welcome.

Comment: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues, though this could also be a Debian packaging issue.

Comment: @IljaEverilä: Thank you, I don't know why they don't list github, and why they are not the first result on Google searching "sqlalchemy github". Anyway no deb, I used `pip3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reported the warning to the Github project as suggested by [Ilja Everilä`s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55805937/warning-installing-sqlalchemy#comment98280229_55805937) and now is [fixed](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/4625).